# Unable to Pass python varaible to hive -e

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, hive

I want to get the table name from user using python and get the content of the table using select * .The below code tells i'm setting a variable at the time hive shell invoked.So, this works fine if it is a hardcoded value.But if i will give something like `set x= $table_name` it will not work. It means it is not able to pass the value of table_name to hive shell.

```
import subprocess
table_name=raw_input("enter the name of the table you want to get queried")
subprocess.call(['hive','-e','set x ="mytable";select  * from ${hiveconf:x}'])
```

The link [Python variable passed as hive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626680/python-variable-passed-as-hive-query) tells some way but not sure how i'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a long time back, but I just saw this today. This is how I have done it in Hive:

```
import subprocess
table_name=raw_input("enter the name of the table you want to get queried")

# formulate your command line statement in a string variable
completeCmd = "hive -e  " + "'select * from {table} '".format(table = table_name )
subprocess.call(completeCmd, shell = True)
```

In python 3 , the input statement would change:

`table_name=input("enter the name of the table you want to get queried")`

Let me know if it doesn't work.